# ScrollTo is not wokring

Tags: javascript, extjs

scrollto is not working for panel, I am trying below code

Main `panel` is parent one and others two panel are inside to parent panel `autoScroll: true,` for parent panel used  `autoScroll: true,`

```
 MainPanelRef.items.items[indexValue[0]].scrollTo(0,100);
```

Comment: what is layout of the panel?

Comment: create fiddle i will solve it there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using panelItem.getScrollable().scrollTo, maybe this can solve your problem.